# Is this normal - scoring in the water pump housing?

Tags: engine, toyota, maintenance, corolla, water-pump

Just changed out the water pump on a 2009 Toyota Corolla with 149,000km on the 2ZR-FE engine.  The previous water pump was likely stock from factory. With the water pump removed the housing had some scratches or scoring that seemed strange as the impeller would have sat in the centre area not on the edge where the marks are . Otherwise there wasn't damage to the old gasket or pump albeit a little coagulated coolant in the weep holes.  A photo of the housing is attached;

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen a used water pump without evidence of some scoring.

Light scoring is normally due to particles that are swept around with the coolant, these can still be used.

Heavy scoring, really deep gouges and worn blade edges are usually due to bearing failure, accompanied by noises, which means replacement.